# Split CSV with delimiter and text quantifier

Tags: c#, string

I have a row like

```
string row = "1;\"2\";\"3;4\";\"5\"6\";\"7;\"8\";9\"";
```

now I want to split the row into this result

```
[1],[2],[3;4],[5"6],[7;"8],[9"]
```

Delimiter: `;` Quantifier: `"`

unfortunately the `[5"6],[7;"8]` are merged togeter

Code

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitCSV(string input, char separator, char quotechar)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    bool escaped = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] == separator && !escaped)
        {
            yield return sb.ToString();
            sb.Clear();
        }
        else if (input[i] == separator && escaped)
        {
            sb.Append(input[i]);
        }
        else if (input[i] == quotechar)
        {
            escaped = !escaped;
            sb.Append(input[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(input[i]);
        }
    }
    yield return sb.ToString();
}
```

Is there a mistake in my code or is the input invalid according to csv convention?

**Update**: Please avoid sugestions about third party librarys

Comment: I would use a CSV parser library, as they're designed for this sort of thing. Is there any particular reason why you need to implement it yourself?

Comment: Which character are you considering as separator here?

Comment: Why are `1` and `2` seperated into two elements of your result, while `7` and `8` ar not? To me they seem exactly similar.

Comment: @HimBromBeere `"7;"8"` are surrounded by text qualifier characters `"`

Comment: Your input string is not in a valid format.  `"5"6"` should `"5\"6"` or `\"5\\"6\"`

Comment: So it reads the " before the 5 then the matching one after, then there's a new opening quote after the 6, so the `;` after the 6 is inside the quote so it splits after the 7.  If you split this (correctly) *manually* you get:  `1;` 
`"2";` 
`"3;4";` 
`"5"6";"7;` 
`"8";` 
`9`

Comment: @freedomn-m I agree with the first part of your comment, but in CSV quotes are escaped as `""` as far as I know, not `\"` so they would need `\"\"`

Comment: *"Is there a mistake in my code or is the input invalid according to csv convention?"* It's invalid. `"5"6"` should be `"5""6"` (`\"5\"\"6\"` in c#). Same goes for `"7;"8"` of course.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer is correct, I was escaping the (backslash), but it should be double quotes to create a single quote in a csv, so yes, it should be `"5""6"` or inside a string `\"5\"\"6\"`

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer when I add a second `"` to escape this character, both are added into the result `[5"6]` becomes `[5""6]`

Comment: @Dr.Snail That part is probably a problem with your code, haven't checked that far yet. **Update:** Yes, it's a problem with the code. You need to check for double-double-quotes when you are within a quoted section. The RFC is a bit short on this topic so I'm not 100% sure if this would be a quick fix for your current code or if it needs a complete re-work.

Comment: `if (input[i] == quotechar) .. sb.Append(input[i]);` don't add the quote when it's used as an escape.  ie `"1";"2"` should give `1,2` not `"1","2"`.

Comment: Why not use `TextFieldParser`? It's part of .NET, albeit in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace.

Comment: @Dr.Snail I've written up some test-cases that might help you with your parser. Should contain all edge-cases that might trip up your current implementation: https://pastebin.com/LBG6DgyJ (including leading and tailing separators)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is here, that you use the quote char also inside a quote. In your if/else you don't have taken care of this! Instead with each quote char you toggle `escaped`.

What about this:

```
else if (input[i] == quotechar)
{
    if (i+1<input.Length && input[i+1]==separator)
        escaped = !escaped;
    else
        sb.Append(input[i]);
}
```

BTW: If the original CSV string is correct I cannot say -.-

Answer (score 2):

You mismatched the quotechars.
See the actual groups below

```
Input                "1;\"2\";\"3;4\";\"5\"6\";\"7;\"8\";9\"";
Groups                  └───┘ └─────┘ └───┘ └───┘  └───┘  └─
Remaining separators   ;     ;       ;            ;     ;
Result                1,  2  , 3  4  ,  5  6     7,  8  ,9
```